# Unable to click on button in pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, pycharm, selenium-ide

I have written the code as below but am unable to click on the search button.
I have used xpath and id ,not sure what is the error:

Search Button
    Wait Until Page Contains Element     xpath=.//*[@id='gwt-uid-117']
    Click Button    xpath=.//*[@id='gwt-uid-117']

Answer (score 1):

Remove dot(.) and try this.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='gwt-uid-117']").click()
```

or

Remove dot(.) and one slash(/) and try.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/[@id='gwt-uid-117']").click()
```

Comment: i did try but am getting this error: A Resource file with reusable keywords and Variables

Comment: I need to use the keyword Click Button

Comment: I think u r copying xpath from chrome if so means then copy xpath from Firefox and try. It will work.